# Is there any quantum operator for mode as there is for mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, operators, momentum

I am quite familiar with the position and momentum operators and expectation value or simply the average position or momentum
But sometimes experiments may require the mode too. But that is only possible after plotting the $|\psi(x)|^2$ on a graph. Is there any operator that can help us to find mode position or momentum without plotting the wavefunction squared.

Comment: I'm not what you mean by "plotting". Why isn't the solution *x* of $\partial_x |\psi (x)|^2=0$ with a negative second derivative, if it existed, unsatisfactory to you?

Comment: By plotting I mean this, https://useruploads.socratic.org/JpYJHFVERJGWzrukURpc_hy2s.gif

Comment: ? You have the analytical form, so take the maximum. Your highlighted *2s* state is bimodal, and you need to specify which maximum you are interested in: the absolute one, or the secondary one. You have failed to clarify what it's all about, essentially...